# Unreal Engine 4 - Any suggestions on how I can I prevent my actor from "flying" by standing on top of an object while lifting it?

Tags: c++, game-physics, unreal-engine4

I have a code that changes the position of an object when grabbed to 100 units in front of the camera, this allows the player to stand on top of an object and pick it up causing him to fly towards wherever the camera is pointing.

Example: In this picture, I stood on top of a movable red rock. While on top I picked it up and moved my camera upwards which caused the rock to move to that position while carrying the actor. Because of this, I can quickly move to anywhere on the map by standing on top of an object and picking it up.

[image: lifting object while actor is on it]

The skeletal mesh is unrelated to the grab function and the range of the grab is set to keep movable objects close to the skeletal mesh (like lifting this pebble) if that helps.

[image]

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to disable collisions for the picked up object and your mesh as long as it is picked up.

Then reenable collisions when the player drops the object.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your objects have some sort of toggle-able state that determines whether they can be picked up or not. One solution to the problem you are facing would be to cast a ray from the bottom of the player and if that ray hits an object that can be picked up, temporarily disable the ability to pick the object up. This introduces a new problem of stacking up two objects and moving the bottom object however. Alternatively you could also change objects so that when you are holding them, the collider is disabled on the object. There are many more ways you could go about solving this issue, but without knowing in detail what you are trying to accomplish by holding objects, it would be hard for anyone but yourself to choose the appropriate solution.